# Stop github from asking for passphase in bash file

Tags: git, github

I have a bash script that need to install something from my github.  It asks for a passphase.  How can I stop that?

I added the following:

```
  git config --global user.name "test"
  git config --global user.email test@gmail.com
  git config --global github.token 0000000000000
```

and I checked out as follows:

```
git@github.com:test/test.git
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a ssh key if you don't have one

```
# ssh-keygen
```

And then tell github about it by going to the ssh settings in your account preferences (https://github.com/account/ssh).  In there, add `another public key` and copy in the contents of your `~/.id_rsa.pub` file (make ***sure*** you use the .pub file and not the one without it).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new ssh key or replace the ssh key that you've registered with github with one that doesn't have a password.

This isn't secure, but will work.